# When I am trying to run the code it gives error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, computer-vision, syntax-error

I am trying to run the code in Jupyter notebook but it shows error `SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop`

```
import cv2
import sys
cpt=0
vidStream=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    ret,frame=vidStream.read()
cv2.imshow("Test Frame", frame)    
cv2.imwrite(r"E:\Face_Detection_Project\Test_images\0\image%04i.jpg" %cpt,frame)
cpt +=1
if cv2.waitKey(10)==ord('q'):
    break
```

Comment: Bad indentation.

Comment: Error says everything, check where while loop ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break should be inside the `while` loop. to be inside, you need to add indentation, like this:

```
import cv2
import sys
cpt=0
vidStream=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    ret,frame=vidStream.read()
    cv2.imshow("Test Frame", frame)    
    cv2.imwrite(r"E:\Face_Detection_Project\Test_images\0\image%04i.jpg" %cpt,frame)
    cpt +=1
    if cv2.waitKey(10)==ord('q'):
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

`break` is used to break off from a loop. Outside a loop, `break` statement has no scope. You should put it inside the `while` loop.
Read the [break](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html) documentation for more information.